# Keras nomalise axis argument

Tags: tensorflow, keras

`x_train = tf.keras.utils.normalize(x_train,axis = 1)`

Guys what's the axis argument here really means?? My image shape is (60000,28,28)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`axis` means the axis along which to normalize. In your case, for each example among 60,000 examples, with `axis = 1`, all the rows of each matrix 28x28 will be normalized.

Basically, your data has shape `(60000, 28, 28)`. This means `axis` can be 0, 1 or 2:

```
axis=0 -> 60,000 elements
axis=1 -> 28 elements
axis=2 -> 28 elements
```

Comment: I have answered it already. Please check it again.

Comment: and what if axis = 0 ??

Comment: It will normalize 60,000 matrices with shape `28x28`.

Comment: if the axis = 2 then it will normalize each rows of 28*28 image for each 60000 images?

Comment: Each column, not row.

Comment: how do you know that its a column by looking into the axis?

Comment: For the shape of a 2D array/matrix, row always comes first.

Comment: so axis = 0 means each row and axis 1 = each column and axis = 2 each column??

Comment: what am i missing here?

Comment: also why differentiating the normalising using rows and columns as long as they both normalise full pixels right?

Comment: If you want to normalize all the pixels in the image, the axis should be 0.

Comment: If you still do not understand, try to create a simpler version for example (10,3,3) so that you can play around with axis=0, 1 and 2 to get more insights from the outputs.